# Read last frame from PiCamera Ring Buffer

Tags: python, picamera

I am building a motion detector using PiCamera that sends an image to a message queue to have ML detect a person (or not) which then responds back to the client. The motion detection code is mostly lifted from pyimagesearch.com and is working well.

I now want to save video (including the original few frames) once I know a person is detected. Because of the delay in detecting a human (~3 secs) I plan on using a circularIO ring buffer to ensure I capture the initial few seconds of movement. This means I need to change how I loop through frames in detecting motion. Currently I am using:

```
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=tuple(resolution))
camera = PiCamera()
for f in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    frame = f.array
    # resize, blur, grayscale frame etc.
    # compare to average of last few frames to detect motion
```

My understanding is this just grabs the Latest frame (ie. not every frame) and keeps on looping until motion is detected. This is what I want as I dont want the process to lag behind real-time by trying to check every frame.

To change this looping logic to leverage the ring buffer I think I can use something like this:

```
camera = PiCamera()
with camera:
    ringbuf = picamera.PiCameraCircularIO(camera, seconds=60)
    camera.start_recording(ringbuf, format='h264')
        while True:
            # HOW TO GET LATEST FRAME FROM ringbuf???
            # resize, blur, grayscale frame etc.
            # compare to average of last few frames to detect motion
```

As indicated in the snippet above, how can I get the latest frame as a numpy array from ringbuf to perform by motion detection checking? I have seen examples that get every frame by adding motion_output=detect_function when start_recording is called, but this will check every frame and I dont want the process to lag behind real-time action.

Comment: did you see [Advanced Recipes](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes2.html) in PiCamer documentation? There are some example with numpy.array but I don't know if they works with video stream. But maybe it uses pure Python code (without C/C++ code) so you could see source code and learn how to do it with video.

Comment: in Advanced Recipes  in [Custom outputs](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes2.html#custom-outputs) I see example which uses `start_recording` with custom class `MyMotionDetector` which converts frame to numpy array.

Comment: maybe you should check if `PiCameraCircularIO` is created in pure Python and then you could use it with some modifications.

Comment: documentation for [PiCameraCircularIO](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/api_streams.html#picamera.streams.PiCameraCircularIO) shows it has variable `.frames` and maybe you can get last frame with `ringbuf.frames[-1]`

Comment: Thanks @furas. I just realised that the code I am using now puts each frame into PiRGBArray by using format="bgr" in capture_continuous. But I think for CircularIO to record a rolling chunk of video it needs to be format='h264'. So I would also need a way to extract a frame from h264 and convert to RGB.

Comment: The documentation is not very clear on how to use the frames capabilitity and whether you can extract a single frame. If I try to print(ringbuf.frames[-1]) then I get the following error
"TypeError: 'PiCameraDequeFrames' object does not support indexing".
I also cannot rune a len() on the frames

Comment: Good tip regarding advanced recipes. I see that you can quickly switch between formats if you keep to using video port. presumably you just lose a frame or two from the video. This example here might work: https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.12/recipes2.html#splitting-to-from-a-circular-stream

Answer (score 0):

So I seem to have solved this. Solution is as below. I am guessing I lose a frame every time I switch to the detect_motion function, but that is fine by me. Use of  saveAt lets me export the video to file after a fixed number of seconds once motion is detected.

```
def detect_motion(camera):
    camera.capture(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True)
    frame = rawCapture.array
    # resize, blur, grayscale frame etc.
    # compare to average of last few frames to detect motion    


with camera:
    stream = PiCameraCircularIO(camera, seconds=60)
    camera.start_recording(stream, format='h264')
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(.3)
            if detect_motion(camera):
                print('Motion detected!')
                saveAt = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=30)
            else:
                print('Nothing to see here')
            if saveAt:
                print((saveAt - datetime.now()).seconds)
                if saveAt < datetime.now():
                    write_video(stream)
                    saveAt = None
```

Comment: So I have basically copied the code that is used on their docs site. But the ringbuffer approach using PiCameraCircularIO simply does not work. I get a massive video file containing however long it ran for.